# bisig PPA causing 404 error?

Tags: 10.04, ppa, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I need default source list for ubuntu 10.04.

Can anybody help me?

Here is Mine:---

```
# Ubuntu supported packages
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

#Canonical Commercial Repository
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid-backports partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid-updates partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid-security partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid-proposed partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid-backports partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid-updates partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid-security partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid-proposed partner


#medibuntu
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free
deb-src http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free

#PlayOnLinux
deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ lucid main

#opera
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ lenny non-free

#google
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ stable non-free main

#Dropbox Official Source
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu karmic main

#Skype
deb http://download.skype.com/linux/repos/debian/ stable non-free
```

This is the error i am getting:-- (sudo apt-get update)

```
Get:9 http://dl.google.com stable/main Packages  [1,076B]                                                         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages                                                                                                                        
 404  Not Found
     Get:10 http://dl.google.com stable/main Packages [735B]
```

and finally :--

```
   Fetched 9,724B in 3s (2,645B/s)                           
   W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisig/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

   E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```