# apt 404 error when when updating with a PPA

Tags: apt, ppa

`sudo apt-get update` command always gives me errors. It's been days since my package lists have been updated. Can anyone help me to correct it?
Here is the Screenshot:

[image]

Here are the commands and their ouputs:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -e ^[^#]

deb-src http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick-updates restricted main universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick-security main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick-security restricted main universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.oss.eznetsols.org/ubuntu/ maverick-security universe
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jcfp/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
```

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep -e ^[^#]  

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://apt.boxee.tv/ maverick main
deb http://apt.boxee.tv/ maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/unstable/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/unstable/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/unstable/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/unstable/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystilleef/scribes-daily/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystilleef/scribes-daily/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystilleef/scribes-daily/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystilleef/scribes-daily/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/pp/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/pp/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/pp/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/pp/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu maverick main #Ubuntu Tweak Stable Source
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu maverick main #Ubuntu Tweak Stable Source
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb http://winff.org/ubuntu maverick universe
```

Comment: post the output of these commands: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -e ^[^#]` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep -e ^[^#]`
*(to copy from terminal: select text, then Ctrl+Shift+C, in description use <pre>...</pre> tag, to format text nicely)*

Comment: Probably the same problem as this person, PPA went away or something: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19170/ppa-causing-404-error

Comment: i just edited the description like roland suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a spelling error in you sources.list. Apt should be fetching

`http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/*`

, but you are missing the *a* in */ppa/*

*Update after you posted sources.list:*

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/pp/ubuntu maverick main
```

should be

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openoffice-pkgs/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
```

And ditto for deb-src

*Update 2:*
Actually, you appear to have both the correct spelling and an errornous spelling, so you should just remove the lines with the missing a's.

Comment: could you please tell me how i can correct it?